# Typeface.createFromAssets does not find the font

Tags: android

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "fonts/AEH.ttf");
```

gives me

> "Font asset not found fonts/AEH.ttf"

I have tried to debug and when doing ctx.getAssets().list(""), I can find my files.

I have tried with 4 font files (ttf and otf), on an emulator and a real device, same result...

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Make sure your `asset` folder is under `main` folder and not `res` folder.

Comment: can't use new XML font because I'm stuck with android support 25.

Answer (score 0):

It works with Roboto.ttf, all fonts used are not compatible.